# How to detect ctrl-t keypress in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a Win32 form with a TEdit control.  When the user presses CTRL-t while the TEdit control is in focus, I want to detect it using the OnKeyUp event.  I need a code example, please, using the Key and/or Shift variables.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set KeyPreview of the form to True, then write this code for OnKeyUp event of your form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = 84) and (Shift = [ssCtrl]) then
    ShowMessage('Ctrl+t is pressed!');
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I found that 30 seconds before you posted and it works.  Thanks!