# Understanding press Ctrl + Plus

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TformMain.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_ADD) and (Shift = [ssCtrl]) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Zoom In');
  end;

end;
```

I am trying to zoom in and out with keyboard (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)

I wrote my code like this:
[How to detect ctrl-t keypress in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000652/how-to-detect-ctrl-t-keypress-in-delphi)

But it does not work, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saying exactly how `it does not work`, but for starters, make sure you have KeyPreview set to `true` on the form.

If that's not it, please expand your problem description with more detail.